# Why do I get this output voltage? Push-Pull converter

Tags: power, power-electronics, push-pull

I am expecting a push-pull converter behavior from this circuit, but I can't figure out what I am doing wrong here. I am using the free version of SIMetrix/SIMPLIS
[image]

The output looks like this, a flat 12V (voltage supplied)
[image]

I am expecting something more like this. How do I get that?
[image]

I am still a beginner, and I make stupid mistakes and have a lot to learn.
Thanks for your help.

UPDATE: New schematic with parameters slightly changed
[image]

Output with the "real-time noise" feature enabled
[image]

Output now without the "real-time noise" feature enabled
[image]

- seems to kick in way later without the real-time noise

Comment: If the circuit is oscillatory and perfectly symmetric, the simulator may need an initial excitation to get it to start oscillating (in the real world, component mismatch or noise will do this). Can you introduce a small asymmetry (e.g. by changing a parameter of one of the circuit elements) or initial condition (however your simulator lets you specify one) and try running it again?

Comment: Simulations are sometimes too perfect, there aren't real life component tolerances that would enable a real oscillator to start. If you make L1 222uH or R1 1010 ohm, and step V1 from 0v to 12V at t=0, does it start?

Comment: A physical circuit will have crosstalk from stray inductance and capacitance. There is no condition for coupling each common emitter for oscillation as shown such as Mutual inductance. There is a huge startup current ramp from the caps shorting the bases to 9V then it decays with some current limit due to the coil DCR and base-emitter resistance  . Adding 10R to each emitter to gnd will limit current and adding some 220 pF from each collector to the other's base will sustain oscillations in the 1 MHz region. Moving one of the 100 nF caps to 0V instead of 9V will start the oscillation faster.

Comment: This looks like a Baxandall oscillator (also often [erroneously] called Royer), but I don't see a coupling term (K1 L1 L4 -1) or resonant capacitor.  Also the dots are backwards (hence a negative K should do). There's also no load capacitance or resistance on the right, but this will not prevent oscillation. Finally, simulators may need a noise source to kick off.